# Trigger external events through Yammer

Tags: rest, api, yammer

I was wondering if it was possible to trigger external events by scanning comments on posts. Yammer doesn't seem to provide a callback for messages posted through the Yammer API. What is the best way this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, there isn't a callback-based API using something like web hooks. Developers typically achieve this by utilizing the [Yammer Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api), but you need to manage state and scan through a list of messages which may be more than just the last message. Make note of all the available parameters, because you can just get the messages model.